# Geoserver WMTS Layer Gridset and ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoserver, arcmap, geoserver-rest-api, wmts

Does anyone know what would cause ArcMap to allow a user to add a WMTS layer service using the epsg:4326 and not a custom one that uses epsg:3857?  How does one create a grid set that would render correctly in ArcMap?  Right now I've started trying to project into 4326 and serve it out as a 4326 projected layer, but I'm looking for an alternative to having duplicate of the same data taking up disk space. Below I've listed the two different layer settings and how they act when added to ArcMap.

***Applications*** 
ArcMap 10.3.1 
Geoserver 2.8.0

***Layer 1***
Store: ImageMosaic 
Data Native SRS: epsg:3857
Declared SRS: epsg:4326
Gridset: the default EPSG:4326 
Result: Able to add to ArcMap, the tiles are drawn but skewed.

***Layer 2***
Store: ImageMosaic
Data Native SRS: epsg:3857
Declared SRS: epsg:3857
Gridset: custom EPSG:3857 whose scales were created from the 900913 gridset
Result: I can add it to ArcMap but the tiles are not rendered. I can use these same settings and add it to Portal just fine.

Comment: When I add Layer 1 to ArcGIS Pro, the tiles are lined up correctly.  For anyone who is trying this themselves, I thought this would be useful knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I came up with on this problem is that ArcMap simply cannot handle default Geoserver gridsets for WMTS and the Image Mosaic plugin store.  If one needs to use a Geoserver web map tile service in a ArcGIS ArcMap 10.3.1 application, I would suggest using ArcGIS Pro to consume the OGC WMTS. For Geoserver I would project the data into WGS 1984 (EPSG:4326) using the Project Raster tool in ArcGIS pro and serve the data out with the native projection and use the EPSG:4326 gridset.  I was able to bring the WMTS service into ArcGIS Pro, unskewed and tiled.