# GeoServer WMS not rendering in ArcMap

Tags: qgis, arcmap, geoserver, leaflet

I have Geoserver spun up in GCP (Google Cloud Platform) sitting on a VM running Windows Server 2019. I also configured a load balancer in GCP to route traffic that hits my newly purchased domain to Geoserver on port 8080.

I am able to access my WMS's in QGIS and Leaflet but for some reason I can't render the WMS in ESRI products (ArcMap/ArcGIS Pro). The WMS connection is able to be established but when I drag the layer in, nothing shows up. I assumed moving the server from HTTP to HTTPS would solve the issue but the issue has remained. At the end of the day, my main goal is to be able to create a Leaflet app, so being able to render the WMS in ArcMap is not 100% necessary. However, it is really stumping me and I'd like to be able to resolve this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in arcmap, you should raise it with esri

Comment: Could be the used GridSet (should be AGOL) or some special paramter like TIME which ArcGIS Pro can't handle well. See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167992/geoserver-wmts-layer-gridset-and-arcmap

Comment: But you are writing about WMS. GridSet issue of course only for WMTS